# Как сделать такую нестандартную структуру меню в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, навигация

Необходимо получить вот такую нестандартную структуру меню:

```
<ul class="menu full">
    <li class="menu_item_l1">
        <a href="/page1621.php"><span>Пункт меню 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item_l1 ">
        <a href="/page4542.php"><span>Пункт меню 2</span></a>
        <div class="child submenu line">
            <div class="child_wrapp">
                <a class="" href="/subpage36541.php">Подменю 1</a>
                <a class="" href="/subpage87871.php">Подменю 2</a>
                <a class="" href="/subpage54354.php">Подменю 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Знаю, что реализуемо через `walker`, но не знаю как.

Comment: И чем не устроило стандартное произвольное меню? Непременно надо дивы с отсутствующими списками что ли?

Answer (score 0):

1) Поэксперементируйте с $depth (сам класс кладем в отдельный файл желательно и папочку создать classes)

```
class CustomWalkerNavMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if($depth == 1){
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"child submenu line\">\n<div class=\"child_wrapp\">\n";
        }else{
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
        }
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if($depth == 1){
            $output .= "$indent</div>\n</div>\n";
        }else{
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }

    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        if($depth != 1){
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
        }
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        if($depth != 1){
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

2) В functions.php подлючаем файл

3) В меню вызываем

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'head_menu',
    'walker'         => new CustomWalkerNavMenu(),
) );
```